# Acumatica - Copy Paste functionality

Tags: acumatica

On my screen, we have 3 level of master child relationship,
with the default Copy Paste functionality of Acumatica ,Parent and first child is copied but the second child Data is not getting copied.

Is there any place/function to debug the default copy paste functionality, or write our own custom paste function on top of what Acumatica is providing with same Paste button?

Edit for Brain Comments -

I have not added any attribute on the View.
First DAC of DATAview is perfectly OK with me, but it is not getting data for second view defined.
Data View -
As the Maint class is inheritade from PXRevisionableGraph -

1. Document (Default from Base graph)
2. public PXSelect<
   Detail,
   Where<Detail.CD, Equal<Current<Parent.CD>>,
   And<Detail.revisionNo, Equal<Current<Parent.revisionNo>>>>,
   OrderBy<
   Asc<Detail.lineNbr>>>
   details;
3. public PXSelect<
   Detail2,
   Where<Detail2.revisionNo, Equal<Current<Parent.revisionNo>>,
   And<Detail2.formulaCD, Equal<Current<Parent.formulaCD>>>>,
   OrderBy<
   Asc<Detail2.lineNbr>>>
   detail2;

Issue - details view is copied but details2 view is not getting copied

Comment: The copy/paste usually hits every regular view (not setup, filter, etc. views) unless you specify specifically to exclude them.  I believe the copy/paste only fires against the first DAC of each view, but I'm not 100% sure of that.  If you have not specified something like PXCopyPasteHidden as an attribute of your other views, can you post the definition of your views?  Might help someone else to troubleshoot if they can see the code.

Comment: I have not added any attribute on the View.
First DAC of DATAview is perfectly OK with me, but it is not getting data for second view defined.

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but typically all the children have a common tie to the parent.  Your 1st child ties via Parent.CD while your 2nd ties via Parent.FormulaCD.  By not connecting the 2nd child via the primary key of the parent, this may be causing your issue although I am not sure.

Comment: Hi Brian,
This was a Type Both are connected with the primarykey that is Parent.CD

Comment: Is there any property on the ASPX which can impact the copy paste behavior??
is there any log maintained by copy paste operation that can be analyzed to check the possible error.

Comment: Not that I know.  The only thing I know affects it for PXSelect (or SelectFrom) views is PXCopyPasteHiddenViewAttribute and PXCopyPasteHiddenFieldsAttribute.  Unfortunately, we are at the limit of my knowledge on this topic.  Hopefully, someone else will know more.

Comment: Ifound that first child is also not copied from copy paste functionality is was the field updated event that was inserting data to the first child.

Comment: Some more details on the issue,
Issue is with the tabItem which has parent dataView as DataMember,
Is there any restriction on same DataViews used in the multiple TabItem.
In my case Parent Dataview and 2 of TabItem is using the same Dataview.
If I remove the specific TabItem then everything start working .. Dont know what is wrong in its definition as shifting all controls to other TabItem working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to the root cause of the issue,

Copy paste works as expected for PXRevisionableGraph as it should, the issue was with the Attributes used with the DAC fields.
IN my case we have used PXFromula attribute that was used to calculate the SUM of the Child rows.
Once that is commented everything start working as expected.
we added the events for calculating the SUM instead of PXFormula now.